# Excluding elements contained within another element with CSS or XPath

Tags: css, ruby, xml, xpath, css-selectors

Here's a chunk of XML:

```
<xml>
  <section>
    <element>good</element>
    <section class="ignored">
      <element>bad</element>
    </section>
  </section>
</xml>
```

It's easy enough to select all `elements`, or all `elements` inside a `section.ignored`:

```
@doc.css('element').text
 => "goodbad" 
@doc.css('section.ignored element').text
 => "bad"
```

But how do I select all `elements` that are *not* inside `section.ignored`?  This doesn't work:

```
@doc.css('section:not(.ignored) element').text
 => "goodbad"
```

...because that actually means "all elements that are contained in **any** section that is not ignored", including the top-level section that wraps everything else!

Additional twist: unlike the simplified sample above, the real XML I have to deal with is nested to arbitrary depth, including sections within the ignored section(s).

And yes, I could just substract the bad array from the full array in Ruby and call it a day, but I'd prefer a pure CSS solution (or, if you must, XPath) if possible.

Comment: "Additional twist: unlike the simplified sample above, the real XML I have to deal with is nested to arbitrary depth, including sections within the ignored section(s)." Then you can't do this with CSS I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how do I select all elements that are not inside section.ignored ?

**Use this XPath expression**:

```
//element[not(ancestor::section[@class='ignored'])]
```

This selects any element named `element` that doesn't have an ancestor named `section`, the string value of whose `class` attribute is the string `"ignored"` .

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "//element[not(ancestor::section[@class='ignored'])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<xml>
    <section>
        <element>good</element>
        <section class="ignored">
            <element>bad</element>
        </section>
    </section>
</xml>
```

**the above XPath expression is evaluated and all (in this case just one) selected nodes are copied to the output. The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<element>good</element>
```